# Edit Code to Split Workbook into Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below that was working until I added some subtotals in the top rows. How do I edit the code so that it will split the workbook into multiple workbooks keeping the top rows in tact on each workbook.

The rows on top look like this

[image: ![[rows on top that I would like to transfer over to each new workbook when the master list is split into multiple workbooks]]

[image]

```
Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow, nRow, nNextRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnValue As String
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim varColumnValues As Variant
    Dim varColumnValue As Variant
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
        strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value
        If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
           objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
    varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
        varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
        objSheet.Activate
        objSheet.Range("A1").Select
        objSheet.Paste
        For nRow = 9 To nLastRow
            strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value
            If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
               objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
           If CStr(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
               objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy
               nNextRow = objSheet.Range("AD" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).Select
               objSheet.Paste
               objSheet.Columns("A:AF").AutoFit
            End If
            Next
    ' Save the new workbook in a specific location
    savePath = "file path" ' Specify the save path here
    objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs savePath & varColumnValue & ".xlsx"
    objExcelWorkbook.Close
    


End Sub
```

Was expecting the code to work when I added the rows after creating the code. I am at a loss on how to fix the code so it works. I get an error on this line "objSheet.Name = varColumnValue" when I Debug the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `For nRow = 2 To nLastRow` the cells (from row 2 to row 7) are blank in Col A. There is a `blank` item in the `Dict` object. `objSheet.Name = varColumnValue` raises runtime error if `varColumnValue=""`.
- `nRow = 2` is used in your code. I guess there is a header line. Change the start number of `For` loop to 9.

```vb
    For nRow = 9 To nLastRow
        strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value
        If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
           objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
```

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nRow As Long
    Dim nColCnt As Long, rowRng As Range
    Dim strColValue As String, savePath As String
    Dim objDic As Object, i As Long
    Dim varColValues As Variant
    Dim varColValue As Variant
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Const H_ROW = 8 ' header row#
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    With objWorksheet
        nLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        nColCnt = .Cells(H_ROW, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Loop through data
        For nRow = H_ROW + 1 To nLastRow
            strColValue = Trim(.Range("B" & nRow).Value)
            If Len(strColValue) > 0 Then
                ' Store data range in Dict
                Set rowRng = .Cells(nRow, 1).Resize(1, nColCnt)
                If objDic.Exists(strColValue) Then
                    Set objDic(strColValue) = Union(rowRng, objDic(strColValue))
                Else
                    Set objDic(strColValue) = rowRng
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    varColValues = objDic.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColValues) To UBound(varColValues)
        varColValue = varColValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        ' Copy header and above rows
        objWorksheet.Rows("1:" & H_ROW).Copy objSheet.Range("A1")
        ' Copy data rows
        objDic(varColValue).Copy objSheet.Cells(H_ROW + 1, 1)
        ' Save the new workbook in a specific location
        savePath = "H:\01 - Merit\2024 Merit\Merit Spreadsheets\AP Copies\" ' Specify the save path here
        objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs savePath & varColValue & ".xlsx"
        objExcelWorkbook.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, I can't figure out how to format this correctly, sorry.                                                                    ```For nRow = 9 To nLastRow
            strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value
            If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
               objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
           If CStr(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
             .....
            Next

Comment: What's the error number and text? Which line? Please update the screenshot include severals rows data (fill with dummy data to avoide privacy leaking).

Comment: error is happening no the same line "objSheet.Name = varColumnValue"                              The comment section won't let me add screenshot

Comment: Pls edit your post to upload screenshot.

Comment: Done. There are about 3900 entries on the actual workbook that I am looking to split.

Comment: `objSheet.Name = varColumnValue
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name` Why the sheet name is updated twice? Click the Debug button when the runtime error dialog pops up. Then check the value of varColumnValue in VBE `Locals` window (VBE View>Locals Window to show it up). I guess either varColumnValue is blank or it has some illegal chars ( \ / [ ] * ? ) .

Comment: Thank You. I removed objSheet.Name = varColumnValue and "Next" after the  objExcelWorkbook.Close line. It worked but it's only copying over the 1st line into the new workbook. The result that I am expecting is a separate workbook for Name and another for Name A with the rows that go with those lines and the top 8 rows. I updated the original post with the updated code

Comment: Is the code in your post the lastest version?

Comment: Yes, the post has been updated with latest version of the code

Comment: I've refactored your code.

Comment: Thank you, the code worked in that it didn't error out. However on my test file, 4 separated workbooks had the header rows but no data, one was empty and one had the data but not the header rows. I don't know - may just end up doing this manually. thanks

Comment: Please remove all created workbooks before testing. All sheets (new workbook) should follow same pattern. I guess some of them are created by prvious testing.

Comment: I added another photo to the original posting of the result I am getting. The top rows are working now

Comment: Please test the code with a sample workbook which is exactly same as the 1st screenshot first. If there is anything wrong, you can post a output screenshot without data leaking. You are going to test it against your real file after that.

Comment: Tested with the sample workbook - same results as I had with the real file. Added image

Comment: same results =(

Comment: It's hard to edit post on phone. It should be `nColCnt = .Cells(H_ROW, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`.

Comment: Is it possible to add additional code to this to maintain formatting and locked cells?

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)